# jQuery ui datepicker('getDate') value localization

Tags: jquery

How to locale the `$('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate')` value ?
e.g. `alert` the chinese date like `(2012年9月10日)`

here is my code : http://jsfiddle.net/8JyDB/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery  i18n plugin. Refer the following links to get localization done.

http://codingwithcoffee.com/files/trunk/index.html

http://keith-wood.name/localisation.html

Hope this helps

Comment: any examples about using jQuery i18n plugin?

Answer (score 0):

[http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#localization](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#localizatio)

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "zh-CN" ] );
```

Comment: I want to locale the date value instead of the UI